# Dynamics 365 CRM On Premise New install Errors when Creating a New Org

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, crm

I have done a new install of Dynamics 365 CRM On Premise. We are at Version 9.1.14.17. I have a sandbox setup with the same version and everything working fine. The new production is different in that the Report Server is on an App server pointing to a SQL server with failover cluster and not on the SQL server itself. When I try to create a new organization I get the below error during the system checks on the SQL Server Reporting Services. If I go on the CRM App server and open the report server URL in a browser it loads fine.

Setup failed to validate specified Reporting Services Report Server http://Host/ReportServer. Error: Error occurred while finding an item on the report server.Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I tried going to the Report server and editing the web.config to take out the reference to the Newtonsoft.Json.  I've also changed the web.config to match the version on the report server with is version 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem causing the error. When I upgraded from 9.0 to 9.1 I started receiving the error. I thought it was coming from the report server but the file causing the issue was in the deployment manager on the app server. I went to the Tools folder in the Dynamics 365 folder on the app server. I checked the version if Newton.json.dll and it was 13. I replaced the dll with version 11 and the error stopped when I created a new org or updated an existing org. I hope this helps someone.